# how to rename file that contain space in php?

Tags: php, space, file-rename

i want to rename file that contain space in name. it work for file with no space but not work for file contain space.
i first run `file_exists()` function but problem is persist

this is my function:

```
    function renamePDF()
    {
        $path = __DIR__ . "/../../uploads/";
        $old = $path . $_POST['oldname'];
        $new = $path . $_POST['newName'] . ".pdf";
        rename($old, $new);
    }
```

what is problem?
thanks

Comment: In this case the OS used might be important. If only to try to replicated the problem. Which is it? Oh, and the PHP version might be useful too.

Comment: os is windows and PHP Version 8.2.4

Comment: Sorry, I don't run PHP on Windows-something, and I cannot find other people with similar problems. You might want to simplify your code, there's no need for `$_POST`, and explain exactly what happens. That might increase your change of getting an useful answer. Also see: [“It’s not working” is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) to help you improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

by this solution worked
before rename file replace it:

```
 $oldname = preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $old);
```